# Deformation of vector bundle on projective space with same Hilbert polynomial as multiple of structure sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, sheaf-cohomology

Let $E$ be a vector bundle on projective space ${\bf P}^n$ whose Hilbert polynomial is the same as $\mathcal{O}^{{\rm rank}(E)}$.

Does there exist a vector bundle over ${\bf P}^n \times {\rm Spec}(R)$ where $R$ is a DVR so that the general fiber is $\mathcal{O}^{{\rm rank}(E)}$ and the special fiber is $E$?

The intuition is that the cohomology of twists of $E$ must be at least as large as the cohomology of the corresponding twists of the trivial bundle, and I'd like to see that realized as a flat degeneration.

The real goal is to use this to prove that $h^i(E \otimes F) \ge {\rm rank}(E) \cdot h^i(F)$ for all $i$ and all vector bundles $F$.

Comment: This is probably not a very useful observation: if $E$ is stable, then a deformation of $E$ should be stable as well, hence cannot be trivial. Maybe for some obvious reasons I don't see, a v.b. with Hilbert polynomial the same as the trivial bundle cannot be stable...

Comment: This paper may answer your question - http://www.math.wustl.edu/~kumar/papers/kpr2.pdf